# Selecting all User Created Tables in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I am using Oracle Xpress Edition. I want to know how to select only user created tables in Oracle DB.?

I am using this query:

```
select * from user_tables;
```

But it showing 24 rows. But i have only created 6 table.I don't know why & from where other tables (like `APEX$_WS_FILES,DEPT`, `DEMO_USERS,APEX$_ACL,`, `APEX$_WS_HISTORY`, `etc`) are showing.

How to avoid those useless table.?

Comment: [This DBA Stack Exchange article](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48158/oracle-list-user-created-tables-in-the-sys-schema) may be useful to you.  You might be able to restrict off tables created when you installed your database.

Comment: Those appear to be tables that you (or someone else with access to the schema) created as part of installing APEX or a packaged APEX app.  Oracle has no idea whether a particular table was created by you on the command line or by an APEX app that you told to use this schema.  If the tables you are interested in follow a particular naming convention, you can use that as a filter.  Or you could put them in a different schema.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:- Is there any way to avoid those table through query..?

Comment: Are all these tables belonging to same tablespace?

Comment: @Spidey: how could the tablespace possibly matter?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:-  YES ,All these table are belongs to same tablespace.

Comment: @Sanjiv: `SELECT * FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'APEX%' AND TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE 'DEMO%';`

Comment: @BobJarvis:- Still some extra tables (like `HTMLDB_PLAN_TABLE,DEPT, EMP`) are showing..

Comment: @BobJarvis:- Hey BOB.. i have tried to run your query, but still some extra tables (like `HTMLDB_PLAN_TABLE,DEPT, EMP`) are showing in output..

Answer (score -1):

These tables were presumably created during any Oracle APEX related installation. You can use the below steps to get rid of them.

1. `SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' AND OWNER =  'your_user'  ORDER BY created;`
2. As these tables have been installed via an application,  they most
   probably have been installed in a small and coherent time window. What
   I mean here is that probably they have been installed within a time
   frame of 30 mins, 1 hr or so. So if you order them by creation time,
   they will all flock to consecutive rows in the output of above query.
3. Identify the time frame in which they have been started and
   finished installing those tables. Write the above query once again to
   filter that time frame out. You are then expected to get only your
   tables.

Comment: what is the problem ? Do they not come within a consolidate timeframe ?